# Minimal polynomial, Annihilating polynomial, characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Consider a vector space $V$ over finite field $F_p$. Suppose $A$ be a square matrix. Also let $C(x)$ is a characteristic polynomial of $A$. Suppose C(x)=$\prod g_i(x)$ for $i=1:k$. It is noted that $g_i(x)$ is irreducible for all $i$.
It is true that minimal polynomial divides characteristic polynomial. Is it true that the annihilating polynomial divides minimal polynomial?

Question is: If one of the $g_i(x)$ divides the minimal polynomial, does that make the guarantee that the $g_i(x)$ is annihilating polynomial? We know the converse is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one point you got the direction  mixed up: The minimal poylnomial divides each annihilating polynomial, not the other way around.

The irreducuble factors $g_i(x)$ of $C(x)$ are in general not annihilating - this is only the case if $C(x)$ is a power of $g_i(x)$ (up to constant factor). Each irreducible factor occuring in $C(x)$ willalso occur in the minimal poylnomial, though often to a lower power.

Comment: why minimal polynomial divides the annihilating polynomial?

Comment: @Mathematics The set of annihilating polynomials is an ideal of the ring of polynomials, which is a principal ideal domain, hence the ideal is a principle ideal generated by a nonzero element of minimal degree, that is, the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal polynomial always divides characteristic polynomial and annihilating polynomial.
thanks @daw

I hope this will help you.
thanks.

Comment: you got it mized up: minimal polynomial divides each annihilating one.